Embedded python script in golang with go routines
I'm working on a Go application that interfaces with Python via CGO to process store data. I'm using goroutines  because I have more than 4M store.
Issue: The execution gets blocked after some iterations.
Here's a simplified overview of the relevant code snippets:
Go Code (main package):
func init() {
    defer validation.FinalizePython()
}

func main() {
const CHUNK_SIZE = 1000

var resultsChan = make(chan stores.Store, CHUNK_SIZE)
var done = make(chan struct{})
    batches := len(records) / CHUNK_SIZE + 1
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < batches; i++ {
        start := i * CHUNK_SIZE
        end := (i + 1) * CHUNK_SIZE

        if end > len(records) {
            end = len(records)
        }

        wg.Add(1)

        go func(rows [][]string) {
            defer wg.Done()

            for _, row := range rows {
                store := validator.ValidateStore(row)
                fmt.Println("Processed store:", store)
                resultsChan <- store
            }
        }(records[start:end])
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(resultsChan)
    <-done

//skipping some unnecessary code 
    go func() {
        for store := range resultsChan {
            
            bqWriter.AddStore(store)
            if store.Cleaned {
                atomic.AddInt64(&addedstore, 1)
            } else {
                atomic.AddInt64(&removedstore, 1)
            }
        }
        
        bqWriter.Done()
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()
}

Package validation
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.19/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib -lpython3.8
#include "cleaner_bridge.h"
*/
import "C"
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "unsafe"

    "github.com/stores" 

type Validator struct {
    Headers struct {
        ID           int
        Name         int
        Address      int
        Country      int
    }
}

func (validator *Validator) ValidateStore(fields []string) stores.Store {
    InitializePython()

    fmt.Println("Validating store", fields)
    var store stores.Store

    store.ID = GetRowField(fields, validator.Headers.ID)
    store.Name = GetRowField(fields, validator.Headers.Name)
    store.Address = GetRowField(fields, validator.Headers.Address)
    store.Country = GetRowField(fields, validator.Headers.Country)

    fmt.Println("to pass to function Cleaned store data", store)

    storeCode := C.CString(store.ID)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(storeCode))
    storeName := C.CString(store.Name)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(storeName))
    storeAddress := C.CString(store.Address)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(storeAddress))
    storeCountry := C.CString(store.Country)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(storeCountry))

    fmt.Println("Calling C function clean_store")
    result := C.clean_store(storeCode, storeName, storeAddress, storeCountry, C.int(0))
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(result))
    fmt.Println("C function clean_store returned")

    if result != nil {
        cleanedStore := &stores.Store{}
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(C.GoString(result)), cleanedStore)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error unmarshalling JSON", err)
        }
        // Use cleanedStore as needed
    }

    return store
}

func GetRowField(fields []string, index int) string {
    if index >= 0 && index < len(fields) {
        return fields[index]
    }
    return ""
}

var initOnce sync.Once
var finalizeOnce sync.Once

func InitializePython() {
    initOnce.Do(func() {
        C.initialize_python()
        fmt.Println("Python initialized")
    })
}

func FinalizePython() {
    finalizeOnce.Do(func() {
        C.finalize_python()
        fmt.Println("Python finalized")
    })
}

cleaner_bridge.h
#ifndef CLEANER_BRIDGE_H
#define CLEANER_BRIDGE_H

void initialize_python();
void finalize_python();
const char* clean_store(const char* store_code, const char* store_name, const char* store_address, const char* store_country, int address_pars_flag);

#endif // CLEANER_BRIDGE_H

cleaner_bridge.c
#include "cleaner_bridge.h"
#include <Python.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static pthread_once_t init_once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
static pthread_mutex_t gil_lock;
static int python_initialized = 0;

void initialize_python_once() {
    Py_Initialize();
    pthread_mutex_init(&gil_lock, NULL);
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('validation')");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import cleaner");
    python_initialized = 1;
    printf("Python initialized\n");
}

void initialize_python() {
    pthread_once(&init_once, initialize_python_once);
}

void finalize_python() {
    if (python_initialized) {
        Py_Finalize();
        python_initialized = 0;
        printf("Python finalized\n");
    }
}

const char* clean_store(const char* store_code, const char* store_name, const char* store_address, const char* store_country, int address_pars_flag) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&gil_lock);
    PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
    printf("GIL acquired\n");

    PyObject* sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyObject* currentDir = PyUnicode_FromString("validation");
    PyList_Append(sysPath, currentDir);
    Py_DECREF(currentDir);

    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("cleaner");
    if (!pModule) {
        PyErr_Print();
        PyGILState_Release(gstate);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&gil_lock);
        printf("Error importing module\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    PyObject* pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "clean_store");
    if (!pFunc || !PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
        if (PyErr_Occurred()) PyErr_Print();
        Py_DECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
        PyGILState_Release(gstate);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&gil_lock);
        printf("Error accessing function\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    PyObject* pArgs = PyTuple_New(5);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyUnicode_FromString(store_code));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, PyUnicode_FromString(store_name));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 2, PyUnicode_FromString(store_address));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 3, PyUnicode_FromString(store_country));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 4, PyLong_FromLong(address_pars_flag));

    PyObject* pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
    if (!pResult) {
        PyErr_Print();
        Py_DECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
        PyGILState_Release(gstate);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&gil_lock);
        printf("Error calling function\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    char* result = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(PyUnicode_FromObject(pResult));
    Py_DECREF(pResult);
    Py_DECREF(pFunc);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&gil_lock);
    printf("GIL released\n");

    return result;
}

cleaner.py
def clean_store(store_code, store_name, store_address, store_country, address_pars_flag):
    try:
        store = {
            "store_code": store_code,
            "store_name": store_name,
            "store_address": store_address,
            "store_country": store_country,
            "address_pars_flag": address_pars_flag
        }
        return json.dumps(store)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error cleaning store: {e}")
        return json.dumps({"error": str(e), "store_code": store_code, "store_name": store_name, "store_address": store_address, "store_country": store_country})

Here are some logs:
Python finalized
Connecting to Bigquery...
Connecting to GCS...
Connecting to S3...
Fetching CSV from S3...
Parsing the CSV...
Processing 104 stores
Processed  0  so far
Processed  0  so far
Processed  0  so far
Python initialized
Python initialized
Validating store [100 8378346 Bird In Bush Elsdon Village Green Elsdon GB 55.23311 -2.103 Village Green]
Validating store [30 7085141 Black Bull Godmanchester 32 Post Street, Godmanchester Huntingdon GB 52.32233 -0.1758 32 Post Street, Godmanchester]
Validating store [10 1455570 La Coquille Napoléon Route Napoléon Saint-Jean-Pied-de-Port FR 43.1528 -1.24208 Route Napoléon]
Validating store [20 374314 Sibton White Horse Inn Halesworth Road, Sibton Saxmundham GB 52.27933 1.45492 Halesworth Road, Sibton]
Validating store [60 9145596 The Castle Inn Bradford on Avon 10 Mount Pleasant Bradford on Avon GB 51.35035 -2.24903 10 Mount Pleasant]
to pass to function Cleaned store data {7085141 Black Bull Godmanchester 32 Post Street, Godmanchester   Huntingdon       GB 52.32233 -0.1758      true  100 [] }
Calling C function clean_store
to pass to function Cleaned store data {8378346 Bird In Bush Elsdon Village Green   Elsdon       GB 55.23311 -2.103      true  66.66666666666666 [No number exists in the store address] }
Calling C function clean_store
to pass to function Cleaned store data {1455570 La Coquille Napoléon Route Napoléon   Saint-Jean-Pied-de-Port       FR 43.1528 -1.24208      true  66.66666666666666 [No number exists in the store address] }
Calling C function clean_store
Validating store [40 1334335 The Oakwheel 17 19 Coastal Road, Burniston Scarborough GB 54.32133 -0.44181 17 19 Coastal Road, Burniston]
to pass to function Cleaned store data {374314 Sibton White Horse Inn Halesworth Road, Sibton   Saxmundham       GB 52.27933 1.45492  inn    true  66.66666666666666 [No number exists in the store address] }
Validating store [0 11081738 Real fisherman's cabins in Ballstad, Lofoten - nr. 11, Johnbua 46 Kræmmervikveien Ballstad NO 68.06593 13.53547 Kræmmervikveien 46  Ballstad]
to pass to function Cleaned store data {9145596 The Castle Inn Bradford on Avon 10 Mount Pleasant   Bradford on Avon       GB 51.35035 -2.24903  inn    true  100 [] }
Calling C function clean_store
Calling C function clean_store
Validating store [50 2536808 The Rodney 67 Winwick Road Warrington GB 53.39456 -2.59368 67 Winwick Road]
to pass to function Cleaned store data {1334335 The Oakwheel 17 19 Coastal Road, Burniston   Scarborough       GB 54.32133 -0.44181      true  100 [] }
Calling C function clean_store
Validating store [70 387155 Turfcutters Arms Main Road Boldre GB 50.80243 -1.47022 Main Road]
to pass to function Cleaned store data {2536808 The Rodney 67 Winwick Road   Warrington       GB 53.39456 -2.59368      true  100 [] }
Validating store [80 542412 Victoria Inn Sigingstone Cowbridge GB 51.43524 -3.47953 Moorshead Farm  Cowbridge  UK]
to pass to function Cleaned store data {387155 Turfcutters Arms Main Road   Boldre       GB 50.80243 -1.47022      true  66.66666666666666 [No number exists in the store address] }
Calling C function clean_store
Validating store [90 340537 The Bulls Head 1 Woodville Road Swadlincote GB 52.78309 -1.51679 1 Woodville Road]
Calling C function clean_store
to pass to function Cleaned store data {11081738 Real fisherman's cabins in Ballstad, Lofoten - nr. 11, Johnbua 46 Kræmmervikveien   Ballstad       NO 68.06593 13.53547      true  66.66666666666666 [A number exists in the store name] }
Calling C function clean_store
to pass to function Cleaned store data {542412 Victoria Inn Sigingstone   Cowbridge       GB 51.43524 -3.47953  inn    true  66.66666666666666 [No number exists in the store address] }
Calling C function clean_store
to pass to function Cleaned store data {340537 The Bulls Head 1 Woodville Road   Swadlincote       GB 52.78309 -1.51679      true  100 [] }
Calling C function clean_store
Processed  0  so far
Processed  0  so far
Processed  0  so far
Processed  0  so far
Processed  0  so far store


This entire design is incorrect. Even if you fix this issue, there'll be a next problem.

I'm afraid your post is not a question. You're expecting us to debug a pretty complicated chunk of code. I would do as  suggested. Even if you need to use two languages (for whatever reason), don't interface them with CGO; use HTTP or RPC instead.

Also, while the chunk of code is big, it omits the crucial parts. Where is resultsChan defined?

i tried to share the necessary information this code is from a big app , i just wanna know if i'm using the correct implementation

@user24714692 can you be more specific please ?

@eik i add resultChan declaration

@sokida If you're designing an app with multiple languages, that's totally fine. However, it's best to design containers and design multiple APIs or simply a "microservices" architecture so that these APIs are able to communicate with one another easily, based on some common grounds. You can use JSON, YAML, or whatever structured data format, so that these APIs use to pass data from one to another.

I am running  this code as task on AWS ECS that executes once and then stops after processing. I'm using Go for the main task, but I need to use a Python script for cleaning functions. Since I have a large dataset (about 4 million rows), I can't call the Python script repeatedly. To solve this, I used CGO to integrate the Python script with Go. This task is a one-time execution and is not an API call.

This will obviously block for len(records) > CHUNK_SIZE, since resultsChan is never read.

@eik i'm reading resultChan i just didn't share it i'm gonna update the code with more details , but when i remove the python script and all it works perfectly , so my worry if i am doing the python inetgration correctly or not

Your question needs to contain all the necessary information within the question itself (not in comments, behind external links, or in images or videos) and ideally nothing else.

i tried to put all necessary information here , what should i add ?

+1 for the time you are invested in this code, was sure a cool advanture. Here comes the downside, its totally crazy what you are do, as first comments told you. You should invest your time to find a better way. I mean why not just execute the Python Script as a sub proc from golang.

@Christoph I'd even argue that this solution is less than optimal. I have yet to find a benchmark in which python beats Go when it comes to database access. Also 4 million ops is... nothing. I am of the opinion that we are talking of premature optimization.

python does just connect to a database for the cleaning ?! when yes why not moving this to go ?
